# why does this list subtraction loop not remove both b and c?

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python 2.7 and I want to remove any items from it that exist in another list.  The loop seems to stop short and I am not sure why it only deletes b and not b and c from lt_sub?

```
bad = ['b','c']

lt = ['a','b','c']
lt_sub = lt
for l in lt:
    if l in bad:
        lt_sub.remove(l)
print lt_sub
```

Comment: Do `lt_sub = lt[:]` instead, that way you're dealing with two lists, and not with a single one like in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign `lt_sub = lt` as so, you are creating a reference to `lt`, not a copy. When you iterate through `lt` in the for loop, once you remove `l`, `lt` has no more entries in the loop (as it has now been reduced to a size of 2, and you have iterated twice).

To fix, have `lt_sub` be a separate list, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) for an explanation.